# What is the best way to create a function with a single argument from a function with multiple arguments?

Tags: python

In python, I have a function f(x,y) defined as

```
def f(x,y):
    return x + y
```

Now I want to define a function g(x) = f(x,y) for a fixed value of y, determined at run-time. In my specific case, I loop over several values of y, and need to generate this function g(x) for each iteration:

```
for y in range(0,10):
    def g(x):
        return f(x,y)
    #do something with g(x)...
```

The above code works, but my question is if there exists a more efficient way to do this? It seems to me that creating a function object at each loop iteration could become inefficient in terms of memory/computation time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
>>> def f(x, y):
    return x * y

>>> from functools import partial
>>> g = partial(f, y=2)
>>> g(3)
6
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks to be pretty much what I need. Follow up question though, is this more efficient than defining a new function as in my original question?

Comment: @user3208430 How are you defining efficiency; speed? Memory usage? Do you have a particular performance problem?

Comment: Efficiency both in terms of speed and memory usage. I simply want to know if there is an advantage to use this partial class over what I do in my original question, as it doesn't require any import and one could argue it's more readable.

Comment: `timeit` suggests that `lambda` and `def g` are roughly the same, but `partial` is 20-25% faster.

Comment: Cool, thanks for actually going through the trouble of actually timing this!

Answer (score 3):

It's not a real function, but depending on what your `do something` actually is, it may be sufficient to use a lambda expression:

```
>>> def f(x, y):
...   return x * y
...
>>> g = lambda x: f(x, 2)
>>> g(3)
6
```

Performance-wise, it seems to be a tiny bit faster than `functools.partial` even (using Python 2.7.5):

```
$ python -mtimeit -s 'def f(x, y): return x * y' -s 'g = lambda x: f(x, 2)' 'g(9)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.364 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s 'def f(x, y): return x * y' -s 'from functools import partial' -s 'g = partial(f, y=2)' 'g(9)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.378 usec per loop
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not a real function"?

Comment: My do something is calling scipy.integrate.quad for that function g(x), would it work in that case? And if yes, is it more efficient?

Comment: @DSM Well lambda expression are just that - expressions. They don't contain statements, like a function does. Unfortunately Python (needlessly) distinguishes lambda expressions and functions.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: I guess what I'm getting at is that the result of using `lambda` is a perfectly normal function, regardless of syntactic restrictions. There's no reason to write `g = lambda x: f(x,2)`, which builds an anonymous function and then immediately gives it a name.

Comment: @DSM The sole reason for giving it a name for this little exercise was to call it. In practice, if you want to partially apply a function it's because you're passing the partially applied function to something else, which then provides the remaining arguments. Read: in practice, you don't need a name (in this case it seems the lambda could be passed straight to `scipy.integrate.quad`).

Comment: @user3208430: I just extended my answer with some benchmarks, which don't seem to match @jonrsharpe's results of `functools.partial` being 20-25% faster...

Comment: Hmmmm, what needs to be timed is the creation of the new function object AND the call to it

Comment: Bah, I also just realized that scipy.integrate.quad as an option to pass additional arguments to the function on which it operates...for my specific case that's probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The `functools` module has exactly what you need :

from functools import partial

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

plus5 = partial(add,5)
print plus5(10) # outputs 15
```